# how to call a report in oracle9i forms

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleforms, oraclereports

I want to call a report in Oracle Forms. It says use `run_report_object` function should be used. I wrote this plsql query for report retrieving button and it says file name not specified.

Any solution please?
[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Are you really using Oracle Forms 9i like your question says? That means you're using webforms. So does the path you provide for the report name point to a directory **on the application server** where you've deployed your reports?